# Set Content-Type dynamically

Tags: php, content-type

I have the following code, which i'm using to force download of files rather than opening in browser.

```
if(isset($_POST['file_name'])){
$player_file = $_POST['file_name'];
$accessKey = "REMOVED";
$secretKey = "REMOVED";
$bucket = $_POST['bucket'];
$fname = $_POST['fname'];

$zip_url = el_s3_getTemporaryZipLink($accessKey, $secretKey, $bucket, $fname);
$mp3_url = el_s3_getTemporaryMP3Link($accessKey, $secretKey, $bucket, $fname);    


header('Content-type: audio/mpeg3');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="themixtapesite_'.$player_file.'"');
readfile($mp3_url);
exit();
}
```

As you can see, i pass all the variables from a form. Then use that information to generate a unique Signed URL for the file stored on Amazon S3.

If the file is an MP3 i need it to use the $mp3_url and if it's a Zip file i need to use the $zip_url.

This has to be really simple, but i've been sat in front of this screen all day now i've got a complete mind blank!

Any help appreciated.

Comment: create an array holding extension. Check extension of requested file and set up content type according to that.

Comment: Relying on extensions for content type checking is a bad habit to get into...

Answer (score 2):

1. This code is one gigantic security hole. You've just opened the doors to your server for anyone willing to use it.
2. Use an [array of mime types](http://snipplr.com/view/1937/array-of-mime-types/) to determine a mime type out of extension (you'll need additional security checks though, as relaying solely on extension isn't a smart thing to do).
3. Use switch statement to determine which function to use. After switch you should have `$url` - just one variable storing the extension, not two different variables.

Comment: thanks for reply @MarcinWolny. Could you elaborate on the security side of it? just to clarify the information submitted by the form using POST is not user input. it's hidden fields populated with variables from another page.

Comment: @BarryJarvis There's no such thing as "_information submitted by the form using POST that is not a user input_". That's one of the most common mistakes leading to people having their websites hacked. Though I don't call it hacking: It's _accessing_ the unsecured system. **Any data sent by POST or GET can be easily altered** by anyone with tiny bit of experience in webmastering. Your security flaw is that you assume that POST data is even remotely secure or predictable. It's not.

Comment: The form i use is to download a file, the reason i use a form is to hide the direct url to the file. I populate the form with variables that are set with the necessary information. Is there a better way to force download of the file rather than passing the info through the form and setting the headers ? i'm very new to PHP so am probably making all the mistakes in the book! *P.S. I updated the code to reflect a change i made in it... passing my access keys through the form certainly wasn't wise!*

Comment: You can always pass something like an ID (force type to integer) with file name hash to retrieve a proper file. Working on integers will make you safer. So basically - first you send an ID, retrieve file entry from the database with this ID, compare stored filename hash with the one you got from client - if both match: send a correct file to the client (you can store full filename in a DB).